# How to create this custom gridlayout in Flutter and Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, layout

at the moment I am using `GridView.builder` to create a layout of venues which looks like this: [standard gridview layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UgEc.png).

The only problem is, I want the layout to look like this instead (i.e. after every 4 cards arranged in a grid like normal there is to be one full width card. Then the pattern continues as normal). Each card will display the name of a different venue in the database [desired grid layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6zm6.png).

Can anyone help me to build this from scratch? I have previously used a library called [`flutter_staggered_grid_view`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view#quilted) but the issue I had was that every card had the same name. As such I'd like to build my own (also will come in handy in the future!)

This is the code for using the standard `GridView.builder`:

```dart
if (snapshot.hasData) {
     List<Venue?> venuesData = snapshot.data!; // data coming from db
       return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2.h),
            child: GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate:
                const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                ),
                  itemCount: venuesData.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Card(
                      color: Colors.amber,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(venuesData[index]!.name)),
                      );
                    }),
```

Comment: Why not split the List data into [a,b,c,d][e][f,g,h,i][j] when drawing?  you can control any effect you want

Comment: Let's say I follow this approach, then how do I put all these different arrays together without using `Gridview.builder` ?

Comment: Do you need pagination?

Comment: It's likely to end up being a list of a few hundred entries (max) so loading them as the user scrolls is desirable, but the whole list will be on one page/ screen

Answer (score 1):

From your description, you want to build (from scratch) a custom scrolling layout that displays 4 smaller tiles 2x2, then 1 big tile, then repeat.

A relatively easy approach is to use a `ListView` (instead of trying to use a `GridView` like you were doing) to display the items. You can treat a "2x2 grid" as a *single item* in the list. First, you need to calculate how many rows (`itemCount`) the `ListView` will have. For example, if you have 5 items, the `ListView` will have 2 rows: 1 row with 4 smaller tiles, and 1 row with 1 big tile. If you have 10 items, you will have 4 rows.

Next, when creating the `ListView`, in the `itemBuilder` callback, you can do your own calculation and decide if you want to return a "2x2 item" or a single "large item".

Comment: Thanks for your response! The `itemCount` will constantly be increasing/ changing as I add new venues to the db. If I am to treat the 2x2 grid as a single item, how will that work?

Comment: @DiscoQueenXOXO You can use math to figure it out. For example, when the database shows you currently have 5 items, then that'll be 2 rows - one row for the first 4, another row for the last 1. Later when the db shows you have 10 items, that will be calculated into having 4 rows.

Comment: I'm currently playing with a solution whereby if the `index %  5 == 0` I want to return a wide card, otherwise return a `GridView.builder`. Though I don't really want to return a gridview inside a listview, my searches of how to implement 2 x 2 columns inside a listview keep leading me to just use a gridview as that's what it's for. Do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: Update the maths logic would be: `(index % 5 == 4)` but that's besides the point haha

Comment: It seems it cannot be done just using vanilla flutter :( - others have tried, dang! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61003079/show-grid-item-as-seventh-grid-with-full-width-after-every-shown-six-grid-items

Comment: @DiscoQueenXOXO First of all, yes you certainly can do this using just flutter, also you certainly can put a gridview inside a listview as well, but that's besides the point. I was talking about using simple `Row` and `Column` to form a 2x2 grid, and with a little bit of math, this can be easily achieved without using plugins.

Comment: Would you be able to provide any code to help get me started? I still would like to be able to do this without a plugin if possible!

Answer (score 1):

For any struggling like I was, it seems *there is no way* to make your own custom layout like I wanted without using a package (which seems really dumb to me). HOWEVER, there is a package that does exactly what I needed, so massive kudos to `flutter_staggered_grid_view` as it has saved me from banging my head against the wall! Here is the [final layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhBi1.png) and the bottom of that [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DxQQ.png) and my code in case it helps anyone else:

```dart
        GridView.custom(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
          gridDelegate: SliverQuiltedGridDelegate(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            mainAxisSpacing: 4,
            crossAxisSpacing: 4,
            repeatPattern: QuiltedGridRepeatPattern.same,
              pattern: [
                const QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
                const QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
                const QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
                const QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
                const QuiltedGridTile(1, 2),
              ],
            ),
            childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  color: Colors.amber,
                    child: Text(venuesData[index]!.name));
               },
            childCount: venuesData.length,
           ),
          ),
```